# I have a problem with the Line reading and terminal writing of the Dart program?

Tags: flutter, dart, readline

Hello I have a problem that I always are shown a problem if I try to do a writing function.
I even have written from a solution side the code and its still doesn't work on Visual Studio Code.

```
`import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.write("Hi, please choose a number: ");
  int number = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    print("Chosen number is even");
  } else {
    print("Chosen number is odd");
  }
}

import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.write("What's your name? ");
  String name = stdin.readLineSync();

  print("Hi, $name! What is your age?");
  int age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

  int yearsToHunderd = 100 - age;
  print("$name, You have $yearsToHunderd years to be 100");
}
```

Comment: remove one of the main void

Comment: import 'dart:io';

void() {
  stdout.write("What's your name? ");
  String name = stdin.readLineSync();

  print("Hi, $name! What is your age?");
  int age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

  int yearsToHunderd = 100 - age;
  print("$name, You have $yearsToHunderd years to be 100");
}
Still doesn't work. Now dart missing an identifier is showing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.write("What's your name? ");
  String? name = stdin.readLineSync();

  print("Hi, $name! What is your age?");
  int age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync() ?? '0');

  int yearsToHunderd = 100 - age;
  print("$name, You have $yearsToHunderd years to be 100");
}
```